# Muda cor de shadow do ViewPager

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço esse shadow de viewpager mudar de cor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está a referir-se àquela barra branca por debaixo do texto "CHAMADAS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa cor geralmente é a mesma do accent, olhe na pasta res, no arquivo styles, caso não tenha, adicione essas linhas:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
```

A "colorAccent" são essas cores secundárias de seleção, onde está `@color/accent` você pode mudar para a cor que quiser ex preto : `#000`

Após isso basta colocar esse tema em sua activity no manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

As outras duas cores do style são a cor da sua `toolbar` e a cor da parte superior, onde mostra bateria, hora etc do celular, você as seta também de sua preferência no tema.

Site com várias cores: [link](https://www.flextool.com.br/tabela_cores.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)